# TTL on rows and the the event fireoff in HBase

Tags: hbase

I wonder if there is any functionality in HBase (or any simialr DB) which I can set the TTL for each row, and then HBase gives me an event (writing in java) to write some procedure on the expiration of the row?

Answer (score 2):

HBase has an opportunity for implementing of custom TTL policy. You need to create your own [Region Observer](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/coprocessor/RegionObserver.html) a coprocessor with for following hooks:

- preFlushScannerOpen - called before a scanner iterating over the
  MemStore being flushed is created
- preCompactScannerOpen - called
  before a scanner iterating over all StoreFiles to be compacted is
  created
- preStoreScannerOpen - called before a user-initiated scan is
  started

See more details in the blog post [Pluggable compaction and scanning policies](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.ru/2012/08/pluggable-compaction-and-scanning.html). But be careful and make sure that your modification only affects chosen tables, in another case you can corrupt meta table and as a consequence an HBase cluster.